# Can I limit my dock to only show up on the main display?

Tags: display, dock, settings

I use 2 external displays with my Macbook. I use the Macbook's display as my main display and only want the dock to ever show up on this display. Is this possible? Right now when I mouse to the bottom of my 2 external displays the dock will pop up there and sometimes push the rest of my windows up. I do not want this.

Thanks!

Comment: How are your displays and MacBook screen arranged relative to each other (under System Preferences → Displays → Arrangement)?

Comment: @NimeshNeema why should this matter? My macbook is in the center and I have an external display on either side of it

Comment: Displays and Dock can be arranged in such that the Dock doesn't show up while normal usage on some of the display(s). For e.g. I use a single external display while is positioned vertically on top of my MacBook screen. I have left the Dock in the default bottom position. It doesn't show up on the external display. But generally speaking, it's not possible to prevent Dock from showing up on certain display(s).

Comment: @NimeshNeema it doesn't show up on your external display by default, but if you move your mouse to the bottom of that display (the external one) does it pop up?

Answer (score 2):

Your only options are both workarounds:

1. Uncheck "Displays have separate Spaces" under System Preferences > Mission Control
2. Pin dock to right or left instead of bottom (obviously not ideal if you're a bottom pinner)

More details here: https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-keep-the-mac-dock-on-one-screen-in-a-dual-monitor-setup/

Answer (score 0):

I use a dual display set up myself. Under the display settings you can arrange which display is where (physically located on your desk) with your MacBook display being the main display.

As of now, I have my dock pinned right on my widescreen “main display” and it does not display on my vertical display. This is in Mojave.